# agrupar barras en grafico matplotlib con valores absolutos y porcentaje. y que aparezca el total en las barras de comparación

Tags: matplotlib

## @title Grafica

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

## Atributos de fuente

```
asistencia = ['No sufragó', 'Sufragó', 'Total']
serie_1 = [157143, 89338]
serie_2 = [102489, 165386]
serie_3 = [167545, 267875]
numero_de_grupos = len(serie_3)
indice_barras = np.arange(numero_de_grupos)
ancho_barras =0.3
```

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
```

## Generamos las barras para el conjunto no sufrago

```
serie_1 = plt.bar(indice_barras, serie_1, width=ancho_barras, label='No sufragó')
```

## Generamos las barras para el conjunto sufrago

```
serie_2 = plt.bar(indice_barras + ancho_barras, serie_2, width=ancho_barras, label='Sufragó')
```

## Generamos las barras para el conjunto total

```
serie_3 = plt.bar(indice_barras, serie_3, width=ancho_barras, label='Total')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

## Añadimos las etiquetas de identificacion de valores en el grafico

```
ax.set_ylabel('Número de electores')
ax.set_xlabel('Elecciones')
ax.set_title('Partipación')
```

```
plt.xticks(indice_barras + ancho_barras, ('Municipales 2016', 'Plebiscito 2020', 'Total'))
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
```

## Añadimos un legen() esto permite mostrar con colores a que pertenece cada valor.

```
ax.legend()
```

## Funcion para agregar una etiqueta con el valor en cada barra

```
def autolabel(rects):

     for rect in rects:
       height = rect.get_height()
          ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
          xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
          xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
          textcoords="offset points",
          ha='center', va='bottom')
```

## Añadimos las etiquetas para cada barra#Mostramos la grafica con el metodo show()

```
autolabel(serie_1)
```

```
autolabel(serie_2)
```

```
autolabel(serie_3)
```

```
fig.tight_layout()
```

## Mostramos la grafica con el método show()

```
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Explica la pregunta, porque aqui yo solo veo código. ¿Qué gráfica sale al ejecutar? ¿En qué se diferencia de lo que querrías obtener?

Comment: ese es el grafico de salida, necesito que aparezcan las tres barras (sufrago, no sufrago, total)